# Laravel whereDate and where

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel 5.4, and I need to check both event and created date conditions at once. So I used following code,

```
  protected $table = 'qlog';   
        public $timestamps = false;

        public function getAbondonedCalls(){

        $results =  DB::table('qlog')
            ->whereDate('created', '=', DB::raw('curdate()'))
            ->where('event', '=', 'ABANDON')
            ->get();  

             var_dump($results);
            die(); 

}
```

But this code returns nothing. After removing this line it returns a record.

```
 ->whereDate('created', '=', DB::raw('curdate()'))
```

How to add both conditions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should try this:

```
->whereDate('created', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
```

Comment: $input = $request->get('logDate'); 
$date = strtotime($input);
I am facing problem with this 
Timer::where('start_time','>=', date('Y-m-d', $date))->get();
i am getting only single row

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, if you want to verify that a column is equal to a given value, you may pass the value directly as the second argument to the whereDate method: i.e. without including '=' sign

```
->whereDate('created', date('Y-m-d'))
```